# Wordpress site deleted after failed auto update backup

Tags: wordpress, backup, auto-update

I received an email stating that the Wordpress auto update for my site was aborted because the backup failed. When I go to check the site all files were deleted, everything. I ask the site host if they could restore from a backup. They said sure then changed the IP so that my site is inaccessible until the DNS propagates. Something seems very fishy. How could a Wordpress auto update remove all the files and why would a website restore require a new IP address?

I've had website restores before without requiring a new IP and I've never heard of Wordpress deleting itself.

The problem site was a subdomain, one of many, all on the same server. All other sites (subdomains and the main site) were working fine. The admins claimed that they could find no reason as to why the files were all deleted and despite repeated requests, gave no technical explanation for why they had to move the site to a new server.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the server had a corrupt file system and storage, that explains the failed update and backup.

Regarding changing the IP, the host had to restore to a different server rack or box. Each box has a unique IP address.

Comment: Why would they have to restore to a different box instead of the same box? They told me they could find no problems or reason for the deletion. Wouldn't they know if the file system was corrupt? My site was a subdomain, one of many. Why would none of the other several sites (subdomains) have any problems?